# Find item with max id in a collection

Tags: c#

Hello i have a method that load data and return IEnumerable.

I want to get list of users but with predicate which is the user who have the max value of Id.

I have try :

```
var id = users.Get().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First().Id;
```

it takes munch time so i want to put inside method Get a predicate with where( id is max in all list) so how i do it ?

Comment: What is the id's type? `int`, `Guid`, `string`? Something else?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann decimal

Comment: Is this entity framework?

Comment: What is `users`? Is it a `DbSet<T>` and if so why not just use the Linq methods instead of that `Get` method?

Comment: Moving the OrderByDescending isn't going to be any faster if your still iterating the same result set. If it is EF then you can optimise it by running this in SQL not in memory, but were going to need more details here

Comment: for exemple i do this users.Get( x => x.id == "55") here it is faster when i'm using predicate so what i want is to use predicate of the max value id

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of:    var id = users.Get().Where(e => e.Id == users.Max(e2 => e2.Id))

Comment: @Hawkzey That will be slow because `Get()` pulls the entire table into memory.

Comment: @juharr you are right sorry i assumed an Iqueryable would be getting used here.

Comment: So what exactly is `IGeneric<T>`?  Is it just a wrapper around EF classes?

Comment: @juharr yes we have in this interface many methods like Add , Delete and Get also so i think we i can add a new method Max and then i use it

Comment: It would be more efficient to just use the EF classes directly to create the single desired query instead of one query to get the max and another to get the item with the max id, but even that's better than pulling the entire table into memory.

Answer (score -1):

Your `Get(...)` with the `predicate` parameter can be used for filtering, but that is of no use for sorting the collection or for getting a Max value.

You can try taking just the `Id` values, and getting the [`Max(decimal)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Decimal__) from that:

```
var maxId = users.Get().Max(x => x.Id);
```

This could already run faster because it does not have to reorder everything, it just keeps track of the highest value. And even if it doesn't run faster, it definitely is simpler to read.

Note that if `Get()` blindly downloads all records from the database by doing `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` or by reading to the end of a `DataReader` or something like that, then the speed benefit will probably be very minimal.

If `Get()` does not read everything in advance and the values are coming from a database, then speed can be optimized by making sure that a suitable database index is present on the `Id` column of the `users` table.

If you want to *get the user that has the highest Id*, then you can follow it up with this (using your `Get()` with its predicate):

```
var userWithHighestId = users.Get(u => u.Id == maxId);
```

Comment: Here the problem that my Igeneric<users> does not contain a definition for Max method can i add it ?

Comment: The Linq `Max` function should be usable after adding `using System.Linq;` on top of your class file. Please confirm that your `users` is of an `IEnumerable<T>` type, which is what `Max()` can be used with.

Comment: No users is of type IGeneric i said that in comments

Comment: Probably nobody knows what `IGeneric` is, except you... how can we help you then? Also: additions that have radical impact on the meaning of a question should be made part of the question.

Comment: Updated the answer to use the `.Get()` method.

Comment: var maxId takes munch time because you try to pull all the table in the memory.

Comment: I will repeat: ***Note that if Get() blindly downloads all records from the database by doing .ToList() or .ToArray() or by reading to the end of a DataReader or something like that, then the speed benefit will probably be very minimal***. That seems to be the cause, so try fixing that.